# python double loop for matrix modification

Tags: python, loops

I have to perform a double iteration in data with a shape like `[a,b,c]`. This is the code I wrote but the result I obtain is not in the format type I need.  in the loop dati is the input data.
In my case `a = 512` (reduced using mroi_i, mroi_f)

```
frame_corr=[]
dati_corr=[]
for i in range(0,c):
    f = dati[mroi_i:mroi_f,:,i]  # matrix with dimension [mroi_i,mroi_f,b]
    for j in range(0,b):
        s = f[:,j]
        s_corr = (s-d_mean)/(w_mean-d_mean) #i have to normalize the vector s
        frame_corr.append(s_corr)  # i have to rebuild the matrif f
    dati_corr.append(frame_corr) # i have to rebuild the original data
```

The result i obtain from the loop is a new set of data, dati, with size C composed of c [Numpy Array].
In real, my aim is to obtain a new set of data with the same shape of the original data.

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the final data from the loop, dati_corr, are type list. the aim is to come back to the same type of the original data, uint8 with dimension  [a,b,c]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using this form of loop

```
frame_corr=np.zeros((a,b)) # First i define empty matrix
dati_corr=np.zeros((a,b,c))
for i in range(0,c):
    for j in range(0,b):
        f = dati[mroi_i:mroi_f,:,i]
        s = f[:,j]
        s_corr = (s-d_mean)/(w_mean-d_mean)
        frame_corr[:,j]=s_corr
    dati_corr[:,:,i]=frame_corr
```

Using this double loop I was able to obtain the same shape of the starting data, but with its data normalized.